# Some questions about the trace of $\alpha \in K$ from $K$ to $F$ where $K,F$ are fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I am just beginning my study in field theory, and I am doing a question about the trace of $\alpha \in K$ from $K$ to $F$ where $K,F$ are fields:

> Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension and $\alpha ∈ K$. Suppose $L$ is a Galois extension of $F$ containing $K$ and $H$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ corresponding to $K$. Define the trace of $\alpha ∈ K$ from $K$ to $F$
> $$ \text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha)= \sum_{\sigma} \sigma(\alpha)$$
> where $\sigma$ ranges over all embeddings of $K$ into an algebraic closure of $F$. Then, prove that $\forall \alpha \in K, \text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha) \in F$.

Here, an embedding of $K$ into $\bar{F}$ means an injective homomorphism from $K$ to $\bar{F}$. And my questions are:

$1.$ I am wondering why here the problem gives me the condition concerned with $L$ and how to use them.

$2.$ My attempt to do the proof was to show that for every $\alpha$ we have $\sigma(\alpha) \in F$ but I failed. Then I was thinking about whether I can somehow show that for $\sigma$ we have $\sigma$ fixes $F$. So can someone give me some hint on this or show me other ways of proving it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your displayed equation missing an equals sign?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! I have added it.

Comment: @ZYX In the case of $K/F$ is a quadratic extension, can you give an answer to 1,2 by yourself ? This is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, note that, in order to use the Galois correspondence and related results, you need everything to be in the context of a Galois extension. That’s where the condition on $L$ comes into play - otherwise, you wouldn’t even have a bijective correspondence to define $H$, for example.

As for your second question, I’ll give you a hint: what is the fixed field of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer to 1st question. For 2nd one, I think the fixed field of Gal$(L/F)$ is $F$, because Gal$(L/F)$ is the set of all automorphisms of $L$ which fix every element in $F$. But I don't quite understand what this hint will tell me. Could you please explain more about it? Thanks!

Comment: @ZYX, sure! Basically, the idea is that you can show something is in $F$ just by showing it is fixed by every element of the Galois group of $L$ over $F$.

Comment: Thanks! I am closer to the answer. But still there is one point which I don't understand: $\sigma$ that we use here is not in Gal$(L/F)$, but is an embedding from $K$ to $\bar{F}$. If we are going to show $\sigma(\alpha) \in F$, does it mean that this $\sigma$ is some kind of restriction of something in Gal$(L/F)$?

Comment: @ZYX I’m almost positive there are some theorems on normal extensions that allow you to treat such a $\sigma$ as an element of the Galois group, though I’ll leave it to you to figure out the appropriate results to: (a) extend $\sigma$ to $L$ and (b) show the image is in $L$

Comment: Thanks very much! I will proceed with these ideas in mind and check the textbooks.